# automapper create.map() to a collection property

Tags: c#, automapper

How do you map to a collection of property but only interested with the last record of the collection.

Say, something like.

```
public class ItemDTO <-- destination class
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public decimal PricesPrice { get; set; }
}

public class Item <-- Source class
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}

public class Price <-- Source class
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ItemId { get; set; }
  public decimal Price { get; set; }

  public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have tried something like this, but doesn't seems to be right.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Item, ItemDTO>()
                .ForMember(dto => dto.PricesPrice, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Prices.LastOrDefault().Price));
```

EDIT: And then after that I did a Projection because If I use `Mapper.Map()` It will return the entire result set which is not what I want, I only want the values I needed. So I did something like this:

`Project().To<ItemDTO>()`

Well, basically, I want something like this:

```
from item in SomeDbContext.Items
where item.ItemId == 1
select new ItemDTO
{
  Name = item.Name,
  PricesPrice = item.Prices.LastOrDefault()
}
```

Can above code be done using `AutoMapper`?

Comment: Your question is inconsistent. `ItemDTO` doesn't have a property named `Price`.

Comment: Oh sorry. Typo. Edited it. Think you can help me with my problem?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Are you getting an error or just not getting the value you expect?

Comment: @MikeNorgate Not the right value I'm expecting. How would you do it in your end if you're in that scenario?

Comment: @BoyPasmo I would do the same thing you are. You should probably add something to deal with LastOrDefault() returning null. Can you post some example data and what value you are getting for that data?

Comment: Then after I've created a map for them I make `Project().To<ItemDTO>()` and it says invalid operation.

Comment: You should be making a call to `Mapper.Map<ItemDTO>(item)`

Comment: Yes. But that line will return the entire result set. I only want to get the values I want.

Comment: Can you update your question with some example code of how you are using the mapping and I'll try to formulate a decent answer

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do now.

Try this

```
from item in SomeDbContext.Items
where item.ItemId == 1
select Mapper.Map<ItemDTO>(item)
```

or you could use LINQ

```
SomeDbContext.Items.Where(i=> i.ItemId == 1).Select(Mapper.Map<ItemDTO>)
```

Both of these will return you a list of ItemDTO object where the ItemId is 1

Comment: I will absolutely try this. But just wondering can this be done in --> `Project().To<T>()`?

Comment: I believe you should be able to do `SomeDbContext.Items.Where(i=> i.ItemId == 1).Project().To<ItemDTO>()`

Comment: This does not work, it doesn't populate the values for other fields, it only populate values for the nested fields...